# d3js multi series line chart, appending circles

Tags: charts, d3.js, line

I'm working off  [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) which I have working on a simple server on my end but for some reason won't work when I create a bl.ock here: http://bl.ocks.org/atmccann/6673536. I'd like to append a circle at each date on my multi series line chart with the corresponding color of the line, here's what I have:

```
var network = svg.selectAll(".network")
  .data(networks)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "network");

  console.log(networks)

  network.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  network.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.rating) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


   network.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 5)
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.date; })
   .attr("cy",function(d) { return d.rating; })
   .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
});
```

But it isn't appending the circles onto the lines correctly. I realize my block isn't much help since it's not working, but the entirety of the code is on there.

any tips would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with the data.  It's getting parsed into objects that look like this:

```
{
    CBS: "9.86"
    CW: "13.959"
    FOX: "0"
    ION Television: "7.102"
    MyNetworkTV: "1.189"
    NBC: "0"
    PBS: "13.419"
    UPN: "0"
    WB: "4.207"
    date ABC: "2002"
}
```

It looks like your code is expecting something quite different than this so you should check out the contents of the "data.tsv" file and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my example of creation of multi series line chart with Circle

Here you can change X-axis from "over" to "Date" need to make changes into code.
But you can get basic idea to implement Circle on each date.
In my example circle is there on every over but it's hidden if there is no wicket in that over.

See Example Here,

[Multi Series Line chart with circle example](http://bl.ocks.org/ChandrakantThakkarDigiCorp/bc0cf8e621f23faff5244062c06e82f8)